# What's the Chrome Developer Tools equivalent while developing React-Native apps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome-devtools

Just like we have Chrome Developer Tools to debug React apps, what's the equivalent while debugging React-Native apps? Is there any general approach to be followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you develop React Native apps you actually debug them with Chrome Developer Tools. Your JS runtime, running on device or emulator, is connected to Chrome on your computer. You can find more in [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging)